# Finding a free port with batch

Tags: batch

How can I find a free port with a batch file?
I tried to run a loop and using the netstat -o -n -a it will increment a variable until the port is not found in the netstat list

But I'm also not sure if this is the best way to find a free port.

```
set freePort=
set startPort=80

:SEARCHPORT 
netstat -o -n -a | findstr ":%startPort%" 
if %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 
( echo "port unavailable %ERRORLEVEL%"
  set /a startPort +=1
  GOTO :SEARCHPORT 
) ELSE (
    echo "port available %ERRORLEVEL%"
    set freePort=%startPort%
    GOTO :FOUNDPORT 
   )

:FOUNDPORT
echo free %freePort%
```

Comment: use netstat in a batch may help u

Comment: `findstr ":%startPort%"` is **not** going to work because it also matches `:8085` (which is open here) You should also clean up the code and insert some returns. (And use the code-button in the editor instead of `>`)

Comment: You could change `findstr ":%startPort%"` in `findstr ":%startPort% "`, note the space after the last `%` but you'll also get outgoing connections on `:80` and I expect you only want to skip `:80` for incoming. With `-a` you also get all outgoing connections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to change your

```
netstat -o -n -a | findstr ":%startPort%"
```

in

```
netstat -o -n -a | find "LISTENING" | find ":%startPort% "
```

The `find "LISTENING"` limits your search to only incoming listening ports and you need the space after the lat `%` because else you'll match `:8085` too.

You also had some other errors in your .bat.

- In the if statement you needed to wrap the `%ERRORLEVEL%` around `"`.
- You need the `(` on the same line as the if statement.
- I changed the echo from %ERRORLEVEL% to echo the %startPort%.

Here is a correct working one:

```
@echo off
set freePort=
set startPort=80

:SEARCHPORT
netstat -o -n -a | find "LISTENING" | find ":%startPort% " > NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%" equ "0" (
  echo "port unavailable %startPort%"
  set /a startPort +=1
  GOTO :SEARCHPORT
) ELSE (
  echo "port available %startPort%"
  set freePort=%startPort%
  GOTO :FOUNDPORT
)

:FOUNDPORT
echo free %freePort%
```

Comment: the ports in listening are not already associated with some application? I'm searching for a port that I can associate to a web service.

Comment: You want to associate a port with your a web service **on your own computer** then you'll only need to check the `LISTENING` ports and loop them up until you find one that's not assigned. Theoretically an application could have taken a **local** port 81 for outgoing connection but this shouldn't happen because applications need to start from 1024 for outgoing ports. The connections to **remote** ports 80 doesn't matter. the connection is from your i.e. `local_address:59206` to `remote_address:80`. So your `local_address:80` is still available. With this batch-file you can get the correct port.

Answer (score 1):

Usually net stat command of windows would help you to find port statistics

You could try like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315307/how-to-check-whether-the-port-80-is-available-using-a-batch-file-in-windows-xp) using conditional statements

```
@echo off
netstat -o -n -a | findstr ZXCZXCZCZX  
if %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0
(@echo "port is available") ELSE (@echo "port is unavailable")
```